# Add a remove button to a custom unlimited value field?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm working on a custom compound field that includes a text value and an entity reference id. The field will contain multiple values, so the widget needs to provide "add new value" functionality, and a way to remove values already added (i.e. a "remove" button).

Following the (older) thread here: https://drupal.org/node/1143880, it seems that "add new value" is provided automatically, but not "remove" existing values? Is that still the case?

The thread above also links to a sandbox project here: https://drupal.org/sandbox/daggerhart/1363702. I tried this code, and it does seem to work, although the formatting is a little different.

What's the current best practice for adding a "remove" button to an unlimited value field widget?

Edit: here is a link to a feature request for this functionality in D8: https://drupal.org/node/1038316

Answer (score 3):

there are two modules already

1. [Multiple Fields Remove Button](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_fields_remove_button)
2. [Field Remove Item](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_remove_item)

Comment: +1 for both of these, especially Multiple Fields Remove Button, which implements the standard 'Remove' button functionality that is used for some other multi-value field widgets like File/Image fields.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm using a sandbox project called "unlimitedfield_remove", available here: https://drupal.org/sandbox/daggerhart/1363702. The code is working fine, but the formatting of the remove button is a little different than the standard (I haven't looked into why that is).

After you install the unlimitedfield_remove module, you need to select which unlimited value fields should get a remove row button.

I'd still like to confirm a current best practice, so I'd be interested in other approaches.